# extracting filenames from href elements

Tags: command-line, text-processing, xml

I have a document containing a list of files. What is simple way to extract filenames inside the href element (without quotes)and copy them into the list separated by line breaks?

```
<manifest>
<item id="ncx" href="toc.ncx" media-type="application/x-dtbncx+xml"/>
<item id="css" href="845214570.css" media-type="text/css"/>
<item id="cover-image" href="845214570.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
<item id="nav" href="nav.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" properties="nav"/>
<item id="cover" href="cover.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="author" href="author.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="title" href="title.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="copy" href="copy.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="contents" href="contents.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="preface" href="preface.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="ack" href="ack.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="ch1" href="ch1.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="ch2" href="ch2.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="ch3" href="ch3.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="ch4" href="ch4.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="ch5" href="ch5.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="ch6" href="ch6.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="ch7" href="ch7.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="ch8" href="ch8.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="ch9" href="ch9.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="ch10" href="ch10.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="ch11" href="ch11.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="app" href="app.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="appb" href="appb.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="appc" href="appc.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="index" href="index.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<item id="img-f0019-01" href="f0019-01.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
<item id="img-f0027-01" href="f0027-01.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
<item id="img-f0029-01" href="f0029-01.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an XML file with this simple format, you can use `grep`:

```bsh
grep -Po 'href="\K[^"]*' file.xml > filenames.lst
```

- `-P` Use Perl compatible regex (PCRE)
- `-o` Output the match only
- `\K` [Keep everything until here out of the match](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)
- `[^"]*` Match any number of characters (`*`) that is not (`^`) a double quote (`"`).

---

However, if you had a more complex `xml`, you could and should prefer a proper `xml` parser, e.g. `xmlstarlet`:

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//item/@href' -n file.xml > filenames.lst
```

This can be installed via

```bsh
sudo apt install xmlstarlet
```

---

As you have tagged your question with `python`, of course you can also use that:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('file.xml')
for item in root.findall('.//item'):
    print(item.attrib['href'])
```

Comment: The grep works just fine. Thank you.

Comment: for python(I have python 2.x), it show error `./extract.py
./extract.py:4: FutureWarning: This search is broken in 1.3 and earlier, and will be fixed in a future version.  If you rely on the current behaviour, change it to './/item'
  for item in root.findall('//item'):` I changed, but no any output printed.

Comment: I changed that to be compatible with older version of python.

Comment: Another option I discovered recently is `xq` from the [yq suite](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) which enables JSON-like queries on xml documents ex. `xq -r '.manifest.item[] | ."@href"' file.xml`

Comment: ...or `hxselect -s \\n -c 'item::attr(href)' < file.xml` from the `html-xml-utils` package.